# Fixed/freezed row in tableview

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a `TableView` that displays the information contained in a `QSortFilterProxyModel` (whose model is a `QAbstractTableModel`)

Is there any way to fix/freeze in the `TableView's` top all rows with a specific property set to true, while maintaining filter and sorting for the other rows?

Comment: Useful info [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25484-Functionality-of-QTableView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a specific row always on the tableview's top, I added the following logic to the `QSortFilterProxyModel`'s `lessThan` method:

```
// Get left and right row
int leftRow = left.row();
int rightRow = right.row();

// Get specific data from left row
QModelIndex leftIndex = sourceModel()->index(leftRow, SPECIFIC_DATA_INDEX);
QString leftProperty = sourceModel()->data(leftIndex).toString();
// Get specific data from right row
QModelIndex  rightIndex = sourceModel()->index(rightRow, SPECIFIC_DATA_INDEX);
QString rightProperty = sourceModel()->data(rightIndex).toString();

if(leftProperty .compare("Invalid") == 0) // put left on top if it has a specific property
    if(sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else if(rightProperty .compare("Invalid") == 0) { // put right on top if it has a specific property
    if(sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```